# Do jaywalking laws apply in neighborhoods and other areas with few-lane roads?

Tags: traffic, crime

Do jaywalking laws apply mainly to areas with multi-lane roads and higher traffic, or do they apply even in smaller neighborhoods and 5 mph campgrounds? Is it considered illegal if, for example, I cross the street to visit a neighbor whose house is right in front of mine, separated only by a small road? I'll primarily apply this to U.S. law and assume that any state laws against jaywalking would be similar. I've looked for answers to this question but haven't found anything that directly addresses this issue.

If crossing the street is illegal even in such scenarios, are intersections the only valid way to cross the street in neighborhoods, assuming there are no marked crosswalks? If not, in what types of areas do jaywalking laws apply/not apply?

Comment: This depends dramatically on state, if not locale... jaywalking is at most a state law, and commonly at lower jurisdictions.  There are HUGE differences state to state and town to town.

Comment: As the answers have mentioned, pedestrians typically must yield the right of way to vehicle traffic anywhere besides a marked crosswalk, or at an uncontrolled intersection (where the crosswalk is presumed to exist whether it is marked or not). This has **important implications for vehicle operators**: as a driver, it is an infraction if you fail to yield to a pedestrian at an intersection. The mere presence of people near the intersection can sometimes be enough, in the "expert" eyes of a cop who is having a bad day, to justify a citation. Drive carefully.

Comment: In practice, it should also be noted that jaywalking is seldom enforced in most of the US, except with respect to limited-access roads (freeways etc.) where pedestrians are completely prohibited. This does not make it legal, but a visiting non-American might be a tad confused if they saw, say, a group of Americans jaywalking right in front of a cop, without the cop doing anything about it.

Comment: There is no Federal law on this.  There might be "model laws" (generic well-researched Code) put out by nonprofits or federal agencies to be adopted by states who don't want to reinvent the wheel... but I'm not aware of any on the jaywalking issue.  Note that most states have laws defining where mid-block U-turns are allowed (e.g. single family residential not commercial/apartments).  A jaywalking law could use that same distinction.

Comment: Jaywalking isn't a real thing you should be worried about. Just don't worry about it.

Comment: @Kevin - in my experience in the UK, many visiting Americans get very confused when they see people crossing roads wherever the hell they please, and are surprised to learn that there is no such thing as 'jaywalking' here.

Comment: @Kevin - What every Brit should know about jaywalking (BBC) - In the UK no one would bat an eyelid. In Atlanta, you could be wrestled to the ground. It is a cautionary tale for any traveller - distinguished historian Felipe Fernandez-Armesto tried to cross the road while in Atlanta for the conference of the American Historical Association, only to find himself in handcuffs and surrounded by armed police. http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/6251431.stm

Comment: ##Breaking news: property values drop within Circles, as people realize they're almost trapped!##  (I'm thinking people in places like https://www.google.com/maps/@28.3681656,-81.4485135,18z)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's not a jaywalking arrest. That's a [contempt of cop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_cop) arrest *disguised* as a jaywalking arrest (your link describes the police officer first warning Prof. Fernandez-Armesto, the professor responding dismissively, etc. before it escalated to the point of an arrest).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the answer you seek can be found by searching for the terms "(desired state name) statutes pedestrian crossing."

In the case of the state of [Florida](https://m.flsenate.gov/Statutes/316.130), there are references to the situation you describe. Some of it appears slightly contradictory, but the ones that apply are not ambiguous:

> (10) Every pedestrian crossing a roadway at any point other than
> within a marked crosswalk or within an unmarked crosswalk at an
> intersection shall yield the right-of-way to all vehicles upon the
> roadway.

> (12) No pedestrian shall, except in a marked crosswalk, cross a
> roadway at any other place than by a route at right angles to the curb
> or by the shortest route to the opposite curb.

The contradictory portion appears thus:

> (11) Between adjacent intersections at which traffic control signals
> are in operation, pedestrians shall not cross at any place except in a
> marked crosswalk.

There appears to be no reference regarding distances between adjacent intersections. It's unreasonable for one to be expected to walk a half mile (0.8 km) if there's a mile between intersections. There's an area nearby in which the traffic control signals are spaced about that distance apart.

Cities may have specific regulations regarding such activities.

Comment: Most residential neighborhoods I've seen (having lived in Florida for a while, though this is true pretty much everywhere else I've lived as well) do not have marked crosswalks anywhere to be seen.  Those are only found on the main roads or near urban centers.  If using a crosswalk were required everywhere, there are people in my neighborhood who I simply could not visit (except by car I guess), because their whole block is surrounded by roads with no marked crosswalks.  So clearly exceptions were needed.

Comment: I don’t see a contradiction here: (10) and (12) are general-case rules for crossing any road, and (11) is specifically for crossing a road that has street lights (“traffic control signals”) at each intersection. (10) doesn’t say you have to be in a marked crosswalk, only that if you aren’t, cars have right-of-way. (12) explicitly covers how you’re allowed to cross roads when not using a crosswalk. (11) says in some cases you *do* have to be in a marked crosswalk, but doesn’t apply to every road.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The points listed in this answer do not state that you must always cross in marked crosswalks. Here is what they say in plain English: (10) If you're crossing the road you have to yield to vehicles unless you're in a crosswalk or at an intersection. (12) If you're going to cross a road, you have to go straight across, unless you are in a marked crosswalk (which could take some crazy path across, doesn't matter as long as you're in it.). (11) If you're on a street that has traffic lights at every intersection (like in downtown), then you can only cross at marked crosswalks.

Comment: @GlenYates Yeah, I wasn't disagreeing with the points made here, just reinforcing them because without those exceptions made, most residential neighborhoods I know would basically be trapped from visiting anywhere else on foot.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman But also key is that there is an *implied* crosswalk at every intersection. In any case, the law as stated for Florida makes perfect sense to me: crosswalk or intersection: pedestrian has right of way; other places - go straight across and vehicles have right of way.

Comment: Do you really have a place near you where there are traffic signals a mile apart, and no other intersections in between? That sounds like a limited-access highway to me...

Comment: @GlenYates: I think you're slightly misinterpreting #11. Even in a street that has traffic lights at every intersection, you can still cross at unmarked crosswalks at intersections, because #11 only applies *between* intersections. (By the way, for #12 I think it's not just that you can follow a marked crosswalk that itself takes a crazy path, but also that you can take a crazy path *within* a normal marked crosswalk if you want. But, yeah.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For another example, I searched, "Ohio statutes pedestrian crossing," and it appears to have similarly worded laws: https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-4511.48. Would the Florida and Ohio laws (assuming they agree) both be saying that you're allowed to cross the street in the neighborhood, just that vehicles have the right of way?

Comment: @KevinArlin: I've seen such cases.  Maybe not a full mile, but close.  One being a busy [stroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroad) between an on-campus residential area and popular bars/restaurants, where jaywalking was unsurprisingly common until the city put up a fence to block pedestrians.  Others being in suburbia with an extreme poorly-connected cul-de-sac-filled street layout.

Comment: @KRyan Thanks for your explanation of the three rules for Florida law. For another example, I searched, "Ohio statutes pedestrian crossing," and it appears to have similarly worded laws: https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-4511.48. Would the Florida and Ohio laws (assuming they agree) both be saying that you're allowed to cross the street in the neighborhood, just that vehicles have the right of way?

Comment: @TheEditor My understanding is that in both states, if both intersections on either end of the block have traffic control signal (I think this means traffic lights but it might include Stop signs), you have to use the crosswalk at one of those intersections and cannot legally cross the street in the middle of the block. If one or both does not have a traffic control signal, then you can cross anywhere, but must give vehicles right of way and, in Florida at least, go straight across. Ohio notes that even though vehicles have right of way, that doesn’t mean they’re allowed to just run you over.

Comment: (and for the record, I am not a lawyer anywhere in the world, much less a lawyer in Ohio or Florida, and even more less _your_ lawyer.)

Comment: @KRyan Thanks! Regarding your comment that traffic control signals "might include Stop signs," this link has some definitions of "traffic control signal": https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/traffic-control-signal. The definition is, "Traffic control signal means a traffic control device, whether manually, electrically or mechanically operated, by which traffic is directed to stop and to proceed," would this exclude stop signs since they are static signs which only direct people to stop? (I like hearing a second opinion on what I'm reading but understand that you aren't my lawyer, haha).

Comment: @KRyan Traffic control signals seem to be a specific kind of traffic control device, and the definition for traffic control device is "a flagger, sign, signal, [...] used to regulate, warn or guide traffic, [...]." Are "signals" therefore different from "signs"? Source: https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/traffic-control-device

Comment: @TheEditor Ultimately, you can’t bank on the definitions from a generic law dictionary to perfectly match the precise definitions found in Ohio or Florida law, so I think to start you’d have to look up how those laws define it. Anyway, your first quote does sound to me like static signs wouldn’t be included but I’m not very confident about that (where the original text seems pretty clear to me on other points).

Answer (score 8):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The rules for pedestrians are in [Part 14](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/sl-2014-0758#pt.14) of the Road Rules (NSW rules linked but they are uniform across Australia).

The relevant rules are Nos 230 Crossing a road—general and 234 Crossing a road on or near a crossing for pedestrians

They say:

> 230(1)  A pedestrian crossing a road—
>
> (a)  must cross by the shortest safe route, and
>
> (b)  must not stay on the road longer than necessary to cross the road safely.

and

> 234(1)  A pedestrian must not cross a road, or part of a road, within 20 metres of a crossing on the road, except at the crossing or another crossing, unless the pedestrian is— [and I won't list the situational exemptions].

So, it is flat out illegal to cross within 20m of a crossing. It might be illegal if you don't cross by the "shortest safe route".

Comment: And it's probably also illegal on a limited-access motorway/freeway/expressway?

Comment: @gerrit it’s illegal to be a pedestrian on those roads (emergencies excepted)

Comment: For the Americans in the room who can't metric:  20 meters is about 65'7".  A little more than the length of a bowling lane (you probably should include the distance from the lane to the seats as a better indicator.

Answer (score 7):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

> Do jaywalking laws apply mainly to areas with multi-lane roads and higher traffic, ...

Yes, they only apply **if the traffic density, driving speed, visibility or the flow of traffic *require it***. (§ 25(3) StVO)

---

> [Straßenverkehrs-Ordnung (StVO) § 25 Fußgänger](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/__25.html)
> ...
> (3) Wer zu Fuß [Fußgänger] geht, hat Fahrbahnen unter Beachtung des Fahrzeugverkehrs zügig auf dem kürzesten Weg quer zur Fahrtrichtung zu überschreiten. *Wenn die Verkehrsdichte, Fahrgeschwindigkeit, Sichtverhältnisse oder der Verkehrsablauf **es erfordern***, ist eine Fahrbahn nur an Kreuzungen oder Einmündungen, an Lichtzeichenanlagen innerhalb von Markierungen, an Fußgängerquerungshilfen oder auf Fußgängerüberwegen (Zeichen 293) zu überschreiten. Wird die Fahrbahn an Kreuzungen oder Einmündungen überschritten, sind dort vorhandene Fußgängerüberwege oder Markierungen an Lichtzeichenanlagen stets zu benutzen.
>
> > (3) Anyone who is walking [pedestrian] must cross the lanes quickly, taking into account vehicle traffic, using the shortest route across the direction of travel. *If the traffic density, driving speed, visibility or the flow of traffic **require it***, a lane may only be crossed at intersections or junctions, at traffic lights within markings, at pedestrian crossing aids or on pedestrian crossings (sign 293). If the lane is crossed at intersections or junctions, existing pedestrian crossings or markings on traffic lights must always be used.
>
> ...

Answer (score 5):

Just for information, as you've got Australian and German answers (quite apart from the reminder that within the US, statutes do vary significantly by location), I'd mention that there is no such offence in the United Kingdom where it's considered a personal responsibility to cross the road safely!

Well, just for @Community, despite the issues of attempting to prove a negative, here are the instructions as how to cross the road in the UK - https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-pedestrians-1-to-35

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you mean to imply that even in London, there's no infraction for crossing streets outside of the intersections?

Comment: Not imply - that’s what I was stating.  It excludes motorways (freeways) but you can cross regular streets wherever without penalty, as you used to be able to do in the US - https://youtu.be/vxopfjXkArM

Answer (score 3):

Many laws have *very boring* preambles, which people tend to ignore: definitions, procedural rules, etc.  One of those is the "Jurisdiction" or "Applicability" section, which states in which locations the law applies.

That is the section of interest here.

A campground is private property, and the roads there are not public roads. It would likely be excluded from jaywalking laws on that basis... unless the facility was of a nature that resembled a public road, and they had made arrangements with police to enforce on their roads.  An arrangement like that is typically seen in shopping malls, for instance.

Comment: *A campground is private property* — not if it's a National Park, National Forest, BLM, State Park, or similar public campground?

Comment: @gerrit True. Harper was thinking of (and I had the same initial thought) a privately run campground - there is one near me (my evil twin fixes their computers).

Comment: Nearest major big mall has signs at the main entrances (couldn't remember the exact language...thank you Google Maps Street View): "PRIVATE PROPERTY - UNDER JURISDICTION OF LOCAL LAW ENFORCEMENT". Which certainly means they have arrest powers for theft, vandalism, violent crimes, etc. but I have always understood to also mean that the normal State/County traffic laws are in force on the technically private roads.