# Do stop signs qualify as traffic control signals?

Tags: traffic, florida, ohio, crime

In [an earlier question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73506/do-jaywalking-laws-apply-in-neighborhoods-and-other-areas-with-few-lane-roads), I discovered that in many jurisdictions, such as Florida and Ohio, you need a marked crosswalk to cross any streets/roads whose intersections have traffic control signals. While "traffic control signals" would definitely include traffic lights, do stop signs qualify as such in these states? I've talked with some about it but haven't received a conclusive answer.

For one reference, [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/traffic-control-device) says a *traffic control **device*** (which seems to be more general than a *traffic control **signal***) is "a flagger, sign, signal, [...] used to regulate, warn or guide traffic, [...]." But what we're looking at, a [traffic control signal](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/traffic-control-signal), is "a traffic control device, whether manually, electrically or mechanically operated, by which traffic is directed to stop and to proceed." Are "signals" therefore different from "signs"? While Law Insider seems to say yes, would Florida and Ohio agree? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ohio, a stop sign would be a traffic control device, but not a traffic control signal.

From [R.C. 4511.01](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-4511.01):

> (QQ) "Traffic control device" means a flagger, sign, signal, marking, or other device used to regulate, warn, or guide traffic, placed on, over, or adjacent to a street, highway, private road open to public travel, pedestrian facility, or shared-use path by authority of a public agency or official having jurisdiction, or, in the case of a private road open to public travel, by authority of the private owner or private official having jurisdiction.
>
> (RR) "Traffic control signal" means any highway traffic signal by which traffic is alternately directed to stop and permitted to proceed.

Comment: Florida makes the same distinction in [§316.003, definitions (50) and (51).](https://m.flsenate.gov/Statutes/316.003)

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert And thanks for finding the equivalent for Florida!